# How do I recognise currency symbols in Perl?

Tags: perl, unicode, currency

I'm having some trouble with this.

I am reading in some text and trying to extract prices from it. That I am fine with, but I am trying to write some code to determine the name of the currency from the symbol in the text with if statements similar to these

```
if ($curr eq "\$"){
print CURRENCY "Currency: Dollars($curr)\n";
}
else {if($curr eq "£"){
print CURRENCY  "Currency: Pounds($curr)\n";
}
else {if($curr eq "€"){
print CURRENCY  "Currency: Euros($curr)\n";
}
```

Now this works for $ (which has to be escaped obviously), but not for the Pound symbol or the Euro symbol. I assume this is something to do with Unicode encoding or something similar from what my attempts to google the issue brought up but nothing I found was much assistance. I wonder if anyone can help me here!

Comment: There's more than one way to do it, but I would suggest that those `else {if` things should all be `elsif`, don't you think? Also, you're missing some `}`s there.

Comment: The `$` doesn't need to be escaped if, instead of writing it as `"\$"`, you write it as `'$'`.  Single quotes do not interpolate.

Comment: @Kinopiko I had just copy and pasted an extract of my code to illistrate the problem - Apparently I missed out copying a few closing }'s!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### How to talk about Unicode characters

It sounds like you are having a problem with encodings. You seem to have Unicode characters in your Perl program’s source code. You need to use this pragma (that’s a fancy way of saying a lowercase module name which acts like compiler directive):

```
use utf8;
```

Put that at the top of your program, and then make sure that you are actually editing it with an editor that knows to save it as UTF-8 text.  You able to use the `file` command if you have it to verify that it says that that file is in UTF-8.

An alternative that doesn’t require your Perl source to be in UTF-8 is to use code point numbers or Unicode character names instead of literals.  To get named Unicode characters, use this pragma:

```
use charnames qw[ :full ];
```

Now you can use the `"\N{…}"` notation to talk about named characters:

```
$pound_sign = "\N{POUND SIGN}";
$euro_sign  = "\N{EURO SIGN}";
```

Another way is to use the numeric code point, if you know it:

```
$pound_sign = chr(163);
$euro_sign  = chr(0x20AC);
```

You can use the exact number in strings and patterns if you want, too:

```
if ($text =~ /\xA3/) { … }     # POUND SIGN

if ($text =~ /\x{20AC}/) { … } # EURO SIGN
```

That will free you from having to put non-ASCII in your Perl source, which is probably a good idea even though literal magic numbers like that probably isn’t.  However, you still have to account for your data source being in some encoding or another. I’m going to assume it’s in some Unicode encoding, probably UTF-8.  I hope it’s not CESU-8 from Oracle or Java’s “modified UTF-8”.

### The Unicode ‘Currency_Symbol’ Property

The *only* right way to detect any arbitrary currency symbol that is represented in text by a single Unicode character is by detecting the Unicode currency symbol property, `\p{Sc}` or `\p{Currency_Symbol}`.

Those are Unicode properties, which are character classes you can use in regexes.

You’ll want to say something like

```
if ($curr =~ /^\p{Sc}$/) { ... }
```

But for that to work, you have to have read in `$curr` from an input source in the `:utf8` encoding.  In your own source, you’d say:

```
use utf8;
```

And in a file you open you’d say one of these:

```
# put at the top of your file and be done with it
use open qw[ :std :utf8 ];

# or else when opening a new handle
open(my $new_handle, "< :encoding(utf8)", "/path/to/file")
    || die "can't open /path/to/file: $!";

# if handle already opened, then just
binmode($already_opened_handle, ":encoding(utf8)")
     || die "can't binmode: $!";
```

Technically, you should probably use `:encoding(utf8)` except for the `use utf8;` in your own source file, so that you can’t get spoofed.  Don’t ask. ☹

If you’re using a module like `CGI.pm` or `XML::Simple`, it *should* just work — but it depends.

### Properties of Currency Symbol characters

Here’s the full deal:

```
% uniprops -vag € 'POUND SIGN'
U+20AC ‹€› \N{ EURO SIGN }:
    \p{\pS} \p{\p{Sc}}
    \p{All} \p{Any} \p{Assigned} \p{InCurrencySymbols} \p{Common} \p{Zyyy} \p{Currency_Symbol} \p{Sc} \p{S} \p{Gr_Base} \p{Grapheme_Base} \p{Graph}
       \p{GrBase} \p{Print} \p{Symbol}
    \p{Age:2.1} \p{Bidi_Class:ET} \p{Bidi_Class=European_Terminator} \p{Bidi_Class:European_Terminator} \p{Bc=ET} \p{Block:Currency_Symbols}
       \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:0} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:Not_Reordered} \p{Ccc=NR}
       \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:NR} \p{Script=Common} \p{General_Category=Currency_Symbol} \p{Decomposition_Type:None} \p{Dt=None} \p{East_Asian_Width:A}
       \p{East_Asian_Width=Ambiguous} \p{East_Asian_Width:Ambiguous} \p{Ea=A} \p{General_Category:Currency_Symbol} \p{Gc=Sc} \p{General_Category:S}
       \p{General_Category=Symbol} \p{General_Category:Sc} \p{General_Category:Symbol} \p{Gc=S} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:Other} \p{GCB=XX}
       \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:XX} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Other} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:NA} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable}
       \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:Not_Applicable} \p{Hst=NA} \p{Joining_Group:No_Joining_Group} \p{Jg=NoJoiningGroup} \p{Joining_Type:Non_Joining} \p{Jt=U}
       \p{Joining_Type:U} \p{Joining_Type=Non_Joining} \p{Line_Break:PR} \p{Line_Break=Prefix_Numeric} \p{Line_Break:Prefix_Numeric} \p{Lb=PR}
       \p{Numeric_Type:None} \p{Nt=None} \p{Numeric_Value:NaN} \p{Nv=NaN} \p{Present_In:2.1} \p{In=2.1} \p{Present_In:3.0} \p{In=3.0} \p{Present_In:3.1}
       \p{In=3.1} \p{Present_In:3.2} \p{In=3.2} \p{Present_In:4.0} \p{In=4.0} \p{Present_In:4.1} \p{In=4.1} \p{Present_In:5.0} \p{In=5.0} \p{Present_In:5.1}
       \p{In=5.1} \p{Present_In:5.2} \p{In=5.2} \p{Script:Common} \p{Sc=Zyyy} \p{Script:Zyyy} \p{Sentence_Break:Other} \p{SB=XX} \p{Sentence_Break:XX}
       \p{Sentence_Break=Other} \p{Word_Break:Other} \p{WB=XX} \p{Word_Break:XX} \p{Word_Break=Other}
U+00A3 ‹£› \N{ POUND SIGN }:
    \p{\pS} \p{\p{Sc}}
    \p{All} \p{Any} \p{Assigned} \p{InLatin1} \p{Common} \p{Zyyy} \p{Currency_Symbol} \p{Sc} \p{S} \p{Gr_Base} \p{Grapheme_Base} \p{Graph} \p{GrBase}
       \p{Pat_Syn} \p{Pattern_Syntax} \p{PatSyn} \p{Print} \p{Symbol}
    \p{Age:1.1} \p{Bidi_Class:ET} \p{Bidi_Class=European_Terminator} \p{Bidi_Class:European_Terminator} \p{Bc=ET} \p{Block:Latin_1}
       \p{Block=Latin_1_Supplement} \p{Block:Latin_1_Supplement} \p{Blk=Latin1} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:0} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered}
       \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:Not_Reordered} \p{Ccc=NR} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:NR} \p{Script=Common} \p{General_Category=Currency_Symbol}
       \p{Decomposition_Type:None} \p{Dt=None} \p{East_Asian_Width:Na} \p{East_Asian_Width=Narrow} \p{East_Asian_Width:Narrow} \p{Ea=Na}
       \p{General_Category:Currency_Symbol} \p{Gc=Sc} \p{General_Category:S} \p{General_Category=Symbol} \p{General_Category:Sc} \p{General_Category:Symbol}
       \p{Gc=S} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:Other} \p{GCB=XX} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:XX} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Other} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:NA}
       \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:Not_Applicable} \p{Hst=NA} \p{Joining_Group:No_Joining_Group} \p{Jg=NoJoiningGroup}
       \p{Joining_Type:Non_Joining} \p{Jt=U} \p{Joining_Type:U} \p{Joining_Type=Non_Joining} \p{Line_Break:PR} \p{Line_Break=Prefix_Numeric}
       \p{Line_Break:Prefix_Numeric} \p{Lb=PR} \p{Numeric_Type:None} \p{Nt=None} \p{Numeric_Value:NaN} \p{Nv=NaN} \p{Present_In:1.1} \p{Age=1.1} \p{In=1.1}
       \p{Present_In:2.0} \p{In=2.0} \p{Present_In:2.1} \p{In=2.1} \p{Present_In:3.0} \p{In=3.0} \p{Present_In:3.1} \p{In=3.1} \p{Present_In:3.2} \p{In=3.2}
       \p{Present_In:4.0} \p{In=4.0} \p{Present_In:4.1} \p{In=4.1} \p{Present_In:5.0} \p{In=5.0} \p{Present_In:5.1} \p{In=5.1} \p{Present_In:5.2} \p{In=5.2}
       \p{Script:Common} \p{Sc=Zyyy} \p{Script:Zyyy} \p{Sentence_Break:Other} \p{SB=XX} \p{Sentence_Break:XX} \p{Sentence_Break=Other} \p{Word_Break:Other}
       \p{WB=XX} \p{Word_Break:XX} \p{Word_Break=Other}
```

### Finding all \p{Sc} characters

And here are all 46 of the Unicode characters with the `Sc` a.k.a. `Currency_Symbol` property, current as of Unicode 5.2: (*sorry for the formatting issues; I believe it’s due to directionality*)

```
 % unichars -a '\p{Sc}' | wc -l
       46

 % unichars -a '\p{Sc}'
 $      36 000024 DOLLAR SIGN
 ¢     162 0000A2 CENT SIGN
 £     163 0000A3 POUND SIGN
 ¤     164 0000A4 CURRENCY SIGN
 ¥     165 0000A5 YEN SIGN
 ؋    1547 00060B AFGHANI SIGN
 ৲    2546 0009F2 BENGALI RUPEE MARK
 ৳    2547 0009F3 BENGALI RUPEE SIGN
 ৻    2555 0009FB BENGALI GANDA MARK
 ૱    2801 000AF1 GUJARATI RUPEE SIGN
 ௹    3065 000BF9 TAMIL RUPEE SIGN
 ฿    3647 000E3F THAI CURRENCY SYMBOL BAHT
 ៛    6107 0017DB KHMER CURRENCY SYMBOL RIEL
 ₠    8352 0020A0 EURO-CURRENCY SIGN
 ₡    8353 0020A1 COLON SIGN
 ₢    8354 0020A2 CRUZEIRO SIGN
 ₣    8355 0020A3 FRENCH FRANC SIGN
 ₤    8356 0020A4 LIRA SIGN
 ₥    8357 0020A5 MILL SIGN
 ₦    8358 0020A6 NAIRA SIGN
 ₧    8359 0020A7 PESETA SIGN
 ₨    8360 0020A8 RUPEE SIGN
 ₩    8361 0020A9 WON SIGN
 ₪    8362 0020AA NEW SHEQEL SIGN
 ₫    8363 0020AB DONG SIGN
 €    8364 0020AC EURO SIGN
 ₭    8365 0020AD KIP SIGN
 ₮    8366 0020AE TUGRIK SIGN
 ₯    8367 0020AF DRACHMA SIGN
 ₰    8368 0020B0 GERMAN PENNY SIGN
 ₱    8369 0020B1 PESO SIGN
 ₲    8370 0020B2 GUARANI SIGN
 ₳    8371 0020B3 AUSTRAL SIGN
 ₴    8372 0020B4 HRYVNIA SIGN
 ₵    8373 0020B5 CEDI SIGN
 ₶    8374 0020B6 LIVRE TOURNOIS SIGN
 ₷    8375 0020B7 SPESMILO SIGN
 ₸    8376 0020B8 TENGE SIGN
 ꠸   43064 00A838 NORTH INDIC RUPEE MARK
 ﷼   65020 00FDFC RIAL SIGN
 ﹩   65129 00FE69 SMALL DOLLAR SIGN
 ＄   65284 00FF04 FULLWIDTH DOLLAR SIGN
 ￠   65504 00FFE0 FULLWIDTH CENT SIGN
 ￡   65505 00FFE1 FULLWIDTH POUND SIGN
 ￥   65509 00FFE5 FULLWIDTH YEN SIGN
 ￦   65510 00FFE6 FULLWIDTH WON SIGN
```

Whereas here are the ones in the BMP that weren’t in Unicode 4.1 yet; notice how you can combine properties and negations to pull sets of Unicode characters.

```
% unichars --bmp '\p{Sc}' '\P{In:4.1}'
 ৻  2555 09FB BENGALI GANDA MARK
 ₶  8374 20B6 LIVRE TOURNOIS SIGN
 ₷  8375 20B7 SPESMILO SIGN
 ₸  8376 20B8 TENGE SIGN
 ꠸ 43064 A838 NORTH INDIC RUPEE MARK
```

If you don’t have `unichars` and `uniprops` on your system, just send me mail, and I’ll send them to you.  They’re little tiny utility programs in pure Perl, no extra modules required.

Comment: Unfortunately this is all a bit above my head. Would you mind explaining a little bit more about how I would use this for example?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the only right way to do this, what's actually wrong with scanning for the currency symbols?

Comment: Kinopiko: You’re right, but it depends on how limited a problem domain he has. If it’s just three, that’s ok, but if he can’t predict what will show up, that’s a problem.  I think he has a source encoding issue. If he used `charnames`, that would solve that problem. I should add that to my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to give a link to download `unichars` and `uniprops`? I cannot find those in my Perl or on the web...

Comment: @drewk: You can snag [unichars](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars), [uniprops](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniprops), and [uninames](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uninames) from [training.perl.com](http://training.perl.com/) if you like. Send me mail if you have any feedback on them. Either use `wget`, or, if you use a browser, make sure to save them in the UTF-8 encoding. If you use `pod2man` on them, make sure to pass it the `--utf8` flag, as the docs are of course in UTF-8, too. There’s no Makefile, but you shouldn’t need one. Fix the `#!` line if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Put this at the top of your code:

```
use utf8;
```

As described in the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html), it indicates that the code includes utf8-encoded strings.

Comment: It’s not just strings, but identifiers, too!  For example, here’s a line from a program I wrote yesterday: `my $ʇndʇno = uʍopəpᴉƨdn($input);`.  Cool, eh? ☺  And yes, I used the program to boostrap itself.  You can get it [here](http://rt.perl.org/rt3//Public/Bug/Display.html?id=79214) if you want.

Comment: This works for £ but not for € unfortunately, which is a shame because I would prefer this very simple solution!

Comment: @Sam, also, what about the encoding of your data sources? If you use properties, you can have an ASCII-only Perl program; you just need to set the encoding on the input source correctly.

Comment: You also need to ensure that the input strings you are comparing with are marked as being in UTF-8 by Perl.

Answer (score 1):

The following module contains currency symbols for most well known currencies:

[Locale::Object::Currency](http://search.cpan.org/~jrobinson/Locale-Object-0.78/lib/Locale/Object/Currency.pm)

Answer (score 0):

As @Kinopiko mentioned in his comment to the question, your code style needs some work. Running it through PerlTidy to show the indentation reveals:

```
if ( $curr eq "\$" ) {
    print CURRENCY "Currency: Dollars($curr)\n";
}
else {
    if ( $curr eq "£" ) {
        print CURRENCY "Currency: Pounds($curr)\n";
    }
    else {
        if ( $curr eq "€" ) {
            print CURRENCY "Currency: Euros($curr)\n";
        }
```

This shows us some missing closing braces (`}` characters) which will be syntax errors. At a minimum the code needs two more braces closing the `if` statements.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

if ( $curr eq "\$" ) {
    print CURRENCY "Currency: Dollars($curr)\n";
}
else {
    if ( $curr eq "£" ) {
        print CURRENCY "Currency: Pounds($curr)\n";
    }
    else {
        if ( $curr eq "€" ) {
            print CURRENCY "Currency: Euros($curr)\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Usually though, we'd write it something like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

if ( $curr eq "\$" ) {
    print CURRENCY "Currency: Dollars($curr)\n";
}
elsif ( $curr eq "£" ) {
    print CURRENCY "Currency: Pounds($curr)\n";
}
elsif ( $curr eq "€" ) {
    print CURRENCY "Currency: Euros($curr)\n";
} else {
    print "Unexpected currency symbol \"$curr\" found."
    exit;
}
```

though I tend to structure it like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

if    ( $curr eq "\$" ) { print CURRENCY "Currency: Dollars($curr)\n"; }
elsif ( $curr eq "£" )  { print CURRENCY "Currency: Pounds($curr)\n";  }
elsif ( $curr eq "€" )  { print CURRENCY "Currency: Euros($curr)\n";   } 
else {
    print "Unexpected currency symbol \"$curr\" found."
    exit;
}
```

Notice that at the end of a chain of `if/elsif` I added a terminating `else` statement to capture a potential logic hole which would happen if no previous `$curr` matched a symbol. That's a simple way to trap missed tests, but isn't absolutely needed if your code logic handles the situation.

If you don't have them already, add these two lines to the top of your code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

to tell Perl to be critical about errors and possible errors.